# How to use SAS data set brought to SQL Server temporary table and use with another temp table to join,update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, temp-tables

Using SAS Enterprise Guide Version 7.1 64 bit.

I cannot create base tables in SQL Server thus can only create temporary table for data processing.

I am also pulling data over from a SAS data set to a global temporary table as(the SAS data set is teradata table pushed to sas-(step2). I need to update holiday table.

I also cannot see how many records are updated in the log (if there is a way to get it, it will be helpful as that way i know the code is working) - I have the sastraceloc but that is not showing update counts in a table.

I finally need to update ##t1 (step4) table created in step 1 with fields from ##holidays table (step2), how do I code this? Am I using the execute, proc sql combination correctly?

Step #1

```
LIBNAME tmpdta ODBC DATAsrc=datasrcname INSERTBUFF=32767
USER='uid' PASSWORD="pwd" connection=shared;

LIBNAME loc '/c/folder/data';

PROC SQL exec noerrorstop;
CONNECT TO odbc as test(DSN=datasrcname USER='uid' PASSWORD="pwd" connection=shared;
connection=shared);
execute
(create table ##t1 
id int,
name varchar(50),
address varchar(100)
)by test;
```

-- end of 1

step #2

```
data tmpdt.'##holidays'n;
set loc.holidayexpns;
run;
```

step #3

```
proc sql;
connect using tmpdt;
execute
(
update u SET
fee=0,
month=5
FROM tmpdt.##holidays u
)by tmpdt;
```

step #4

```
PROC SQL exec noerrorstop;
CONNECT TO odbc as test(DSN=datasrcname USER='uid' PASSWORD="pwd" connection=shared;
connection=shared);
execute
(
update xyz
set a.fee=b.fee,
a.month=b.month
from tmpdt.##holidays h
join ##t1 xyz on 
h.id=xyz.id
)by test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` native-query will not know the SAS reference `tmpdt.`, `tmpdt` will be known to your user login only if on the SQL Server side you have access to a catalog of like name.  Did you mean to indicate `tempdb` ?

Per [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n0tpd3yaqvep53n1g8wahav3hgco.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> Any return code or message that is generated by the DBMS is available in the macro variables `SQLXRC` and `SQLXMSG` after the statement completes.